# Integrate Mobile Ad networks in android app

Tags: android, admob, amazon-appstore, leadbolt, revmobads

I am trying to implement following mobile networks admob,revmob,leadbolt and amazon api into my android application.I come to know it is possible to integrate all mobile ad networks in single app by one of the question answered in this forum. But I don't know It is possible or not.Can anyone help me whether it is possible,where can I begin to integrate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mediator to provide an integrated front to several ad networks. THis is the recommended approach. One such is Admob https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation

You will ind a lot of the networks you want to integrate already supported out of the box. For those that aren't you can create a CustomEvent that hands off to that network.

Comment: is there any samples available?

Comment: The link I provided contrains samples.

Comment: can you tell me how can i integrate leadbolt into mediation page

Comment: You create a CustomEventBanner or CustomEventInterstitial and in its #requestBannerAd or #requestInterstitialAd method calls the Leadbolt API.